# Chained Select with NO jQuery or Ajax

Tags: javascript, forms, select, chained

I'm using XAMPP Lite - USB Version and found that the jQuery chained select boxes scripts don't work because they rely on AJAX which is not working on my XAMPP.

I have two Select boxes:

```
<label>Province</label>
<select name="province"> 
<option value="ontario">Ontario</option>
<option value="quebec">Quebec</option>
<option value="novascotia">Nova Scotia</option>
</select> 

<label>city</label>
<select name="city"> 
</select>
```

I need to be able to select a province and load different cities into the "city" name select. I have to do this **without jQuery or Ajax**. FYI It does not matter how long the javascript array variables have to be which will hold all the data. I just need someone to start me out with the script please.

Comment: so, what have you got so far that doesn't work?

Comment: Why can't you use jQuery? It would be possible to do using javascript/jQuery without ajax calls... though it would be a bit hackish - set up an js array of cities which correspond to each province and use jQuery to change the select options based on the selected province.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[here's a quick sample](http://jsfiddle.net/fskreuz/FWsX7/), not optimized but does the job. as said, no jQuery and no AJAX. this one works in standards compliant browsers, you man need to tweak it for IE coz i have no IE to test on.

```
<label>Province</label>
<select id="province"> 
    <option value="p1">p1</option>
    <option value="p2">p2</option>
    <option value="p3">p3</option>
</select> 

<label>city</label>
    <select id="city"> 
</select> ​


window.onload = (function() {

    var locations = {
        'p1': [
            'p1c1',
            'p1c2',
            'p1c3',
            ],
        'p2': [
            'p2c1',
            'p2c2',
            'p2c3',
            ],
        'p3': [
            'p3c1',
            'p3c2',
            'p3c3',
            ],
    };

    var provinces = document.getElementById('province');
    var cities = document.getElementById('city');

    provinces.addEventListener('change', function() {
        loadCities(this.value)
    }, false)


    var loadCities = (function loadCitiesFunc(key) {
        key = key || 'p1';
        var docFragment = document.createElement('select');
        for (var i = 0; i < locations[key].length; i++) {
            docFragment.appendChild(new Option(locations[key][i], locations[key][i]));
        }
        cities.innerHTML = docFragment.innerHTML;

        return loadCitiesFunc;
    }())

}());​
```

Comment: It works fine in FF and Chrome, but not in IE, not even in IE9. And I'm not getting any error report from IE's F12 development add-on. Any ideas?