# select multiple option then display option related value on next select box

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have multi selected drop down box which fill State list and I want to if I will select multiple select State then Selected State related cities are display another drop down box.

For Example if I am select DELHI and UTTER PRADESH then both State all Cites are display on next drop down box.

Thanks for Advance.

Comment: Is it possible to show what you already have tried to solve your problem ?

Comment: try your search for `chained selects`

Comment: this is SUCH a FAQ. look to the right --->

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chained Select with NO jQuery or Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917577/chained-select-with-no-jquery-or-ajax)

Comment: possibly duplicate of [Dynamic chained select box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737113/dynamic-chained-select-box)

Comment: Simple question is if select 2 or 3 or more State on multiple selected drop down box then Selected State related Cites are display another drop down box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to populate chained dropdown list with Ajax and Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763136/unable-to-populate-chained-dropdown-list-with-ajax-and-javascript)